# Gap Between Trim and Brick (Exterior)

Tags: brick, trim, gap

[image: Issue in Question]I'm trying to find a solution for gap between trim and brick around my house. Specifcially the area in front of my house by the garage. When I bought the home, the house had settled and you could see the brick was separating from the trim. Had a contractor come out and he nailed a piece of wood over the gap and sealed it. I'm notice the sealant beginning to separate. How do I go about fixing this issue? I've tried applying more sealant, but it keeps separating.

Comment: Welcome to DiY! Would you mind adding some pictures, including of the questionable fix (and preferably both zoomed in details and a bit more zoomed out overviews)? I'm wondering if there's a foundation problem.

Comment: The question should be, "is the gap forming because the trim's pulling away from the wall (trim failure) or the wall's pulling away from the trim (wall/foundation failure)?". Simply patching over the gap without knowing which is which could be akin to putting a band-aid over an carotid artery cut.

Comment: It's pulling away from the trim. It's happening in the front of the house on the garage.

Comment: I added a photo. If you zoom in, you can see what I need to fix.

Comment: Do you have any information on the foundations? It looks like one part of the building is subsiding faster than the other, causing that tilt.

Comment: It's around my garage and there is no issue with the foundation of the house itself. Should I contact professionals?

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Are gaps or cracks visible anywhere else in the house or garage, for example in separation walls, facades or the roof? And is the garage floor itself tilting/subsiding?